# How to incorporate user feedback into a multi-choice Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I developed a neural network which can classify hand-written digits, based on the mnist dataset. I also made a GUI where the user can draw numbers and then display the predicted digit. I'm wondering if there is a way to incorporate the feedback from the user, so if the model is wrong, the user can tell it what digit did he draw, and next time the model wil lguess correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant directly achieve what you are asking but there is one thing you can do.

Whenever there is a wrong prediction you can save the image as well as the label of the image and add this sample in your training dataset.

Now every time the models fails to predict on a certain example you have one more example in your training dataset. From here you can do two things either automate the process of model training after a certain interval of time or after you have a certain number of new examples to train on.

Note: When you are automating the training process you should choose the model for generating prediction wisely. You should choose a model whose validation accuracy is higher even if that means choosing your old model. Also, you should maintain a separate validation data to test your models on. This validation data should remain constant so as to give a good estimate of goodness of each model.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes I had that in mind but I was looking for something more efficient. I stumbled upon a paper by google where they used secondary lighter models based on a bigger network to classify emails. I will try that one and thanks for answering!